# Configure Realtek USB adapter for multiple VLANs

Tags: networking, vlan

I have a Realtek RTL8153 USB Gigabit Ethernet adapter built into my Dell "docking station" and would like to enable multiple VLAN's in a similar way that Intel Network adapters do it using virtual adapters for each VLAN on a trunked network connection.

I have installed the Realtek Ethernet Diagnostic Utility and there is no option to configure VLANs.

For example, I want to have access to VLANs 6, 10, 50, 60, and 70. and be able to assign my device a static IP on some of them and get a DHCP address on others.

I have looked at [this](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2422/usb-to-ethernet-adapter-supporting-multiple-virtual-lans) posting, just hoping things may have changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bought a $10 1GB USB LAN adapter that has the Realtek RTL8153 chipset in it. This does support 802.1q MULTIPLE VLAN tagging/trunking with the Realtek supplied Windows drivers. I have a Cisco 2960 switch and I setup one of the switchports for trunking and I allowed VLAN's 10, 142,192 and 250 on that Cisco trunk port. You can allow whatever you want. Then I ran a CAT-5 cable from there to the USB LAN adapter and set it up for those 4 VLANS. When you install the Realtek drivers, you will see the USB LAN adapter as a single entity in Windows. When you then use the [Realtek 'Diagnostic' software](https://www.realtek.com/en/downloads) and create your individual VLAN's, that will in turn create an additional adapter per VLAN in Windows.

[image: Realtek - Ethernet Diagnostic Utility]

So I created 4 VLANS's and I have 5 adapters, 1 is the TRUNK and the other 4 are for each VLAN. Then you go into each of the 4 and set your TCP/IP settings, as the main adapter is now a trunk and has nothing to do with the TCP/IP stack. Now my laptop has 4 separate IP addresses, but remember, you can only have the one main default gateway provisioned, like on whatever VLAN adapter your connecting to the internet. If you wanna push traffic out of one of the VLAN adapters that is not part of that subnet, then setup some Windows persistent routes to do that.

I set this up on 2 laptops, one is Win-7 32-bit and one is Win-7 64-bit. I had the most problems with Win-7 32-bit. This method is what I used and I know it works. On the 64-bit I loaded the Realtek driver package version 7.21.1019.2015, which I had laying around. Then I loaded the [Realtek Ethernet Diagnostic Utility](https://www.realtek.com/en/downloads) version 2.0.7.0. I took the one made for my chipset, the RTL8153. Once all that was loaded on the 64-bit machine, it was easy to get into the Diag utility and create the VLAN's.

After you create a VLAN, it takes time for it to build that adapter and place it as an adapter in Windows networking. For you to know its going to work, after you create your VLAN, you MUST see a MAC address populate in that create box in the Diag utility. This is where things were NOT happening for me in my Win-7 32 bit machine. It would create the VLAN, it would place the new adapter in Windows but there would NOT be a MAC address in the adapter box and there would be a red X in the adapter in Windows. This is where a lot of people are having problems. That big red X, even though you have a LAN cable plugged into the adapter. This is ALSO where I believe the original poster here had problems when he couldn't add VLANS In the Diag utility, even though you know you have the Realtek chipset that supports it.

How I fixed this was to go into the main adapter in Windows and UNCHECK every box and only have 3 boxes checked, which are 'QoS Packet Scheduler', 'Realtek Vlan Protocol Driver (NDIS 6.2)' and 'Realtek NDIS Protocol Driver (NDIS 6.0)'. Then when I saved and exited and went back to the Diag utility, I was able to create the VLAN's and see the MAC addresses. In Win-7 32bit, is was the 'Deterministic Network Enhancer' that was the culprit. When I unchecked that on the main trunk adapter, then the extra menus appeared in the Diag utility to create the VLAN's.

Hopefully this may help someone get through setting up theirs. I was tired of having 4 separate USB LAN adapters and the main built in LAN adapter in my laptop, so I consolidated to a single trunk LAN adapter. Some my ask what's the need for all this? I have Cisco lab and I remote desktop into this one laptop and I control many things in my lab on 4 different subnets from one machine. That's my need.

Comment: Actually, I discovered this in late 2019 to early 2020... I don't know when Realtek made that tool available to the public, but it does handle multiple VLANs quite well. Thanks for the "new" answer. I will upvote and mark correct.

Comment: So kind of you acejavelin, thank you. I only wanted to help others.

Answer (score 3):

As indicated in the posting you linked to VLANs are handled by the NIC driver in Windows. A very limited selection of NIC drivers for windows support trunking (multiple VLANs) primarily the Intel server grade NICs. I do not believe there are currently any USB NICs with Windows drivers which support trunking.

In Linux the OS provides the VLAN/tagging support, not the NIC driver, so almost all NICs provide VLAN trunking in Linux.

Comment: Thanks... Kind of what I thought and my research agrees with your answer. Accepted and up-voted.